# Client Server 2 way web communication without websockets

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, communication

I am creating a web application, and I need to establish a client-server two-way communication system. However, I am using shared hosting and so I cannot create a web socket server. SSE would be great, but unfortunately I am unable to send data. I am currently using AJAX to send and receive data. However, due to a fast polling rate (~100 ms), it lags the client. How can I establish a two way communication system without WebSockets?

I think using SSE and temporarily closing it to send data with AJAX might work, but I might lose a few iterations of data, as it needs to constantly update.

Comment: You could try the old technique of long polling.

Comment: Why are you using shared hosting? Nowadays VPS is really cheap, $3.50 to be exact. https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/

Comment: When I was facing same I did as @Pablo mentioned and ditched shared hosting, but what really opened up a whole new world was discovering node.js with express and socket.io for socket-based, bi-direction communication.   I tried sockets via PHP but nothing I found was as rock solid as Node.js / socket.io